# Grabbing sibling's html to set as element's title tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am setting the title attribute of an element, and firing Fancybox, using this code:

```
var caption = jQuery('.fancybox').siblings('p.wp-caption-text').html();

jQuery('.fancybox').attr({ title:caption, 'data-fancybox-group': 'gallery1'}).fancybox();
```

This works fine when there is only one `.fancybox` link on a page, but the problem of course is that I want to use galleries.

The above sets the variable to the first instance on the page, so all captions are the same.

Can I do something like this instead?:

```
jQuery('.fancybox').attr({ title:'jQuery(this).siblings('p.wp-caption-text').html();', 'data-fancybox-group': 'gallery1'}).fancybox();
```

Please excuse my lack of coding skills, but I am hoping it is a simple question for someone more familiar with jQuery.

The page in progress: http://professorleonidas.com/wordpress/formacao/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply to each one individually:

```
var caption;
$('.fancybox').each(function(i, elem){
    // Grab the caption text
    caption = $(elem).siblings('p.wp-caption-text').html();

    // Set the attributes and initialize fancybox
    $(elem).attr({ title:caption, 'data-fancybox-group': 'gallery1'}).fancybox();
});
```

The point of your 'data-fancybox-group' attribute isn't clear from your question, but the above code will apply `gallery1` as its value to all matched elements with class `fancybox`.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Madbreaks! That somehow stops the images being displayed as a gallery, despite setting `data-fancybox-group` as before, but hopefully I can figure that out...

Answer (score 2):

You could make it simpler: having this html ...

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery1" href="image01.jpg">open image 01</a>
<p>I am the caption for the image 01</p>
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery1" href="image02.jpg">open image 02</a>
<p>I am the caption for the image 02</p>
```

... use this script:

```
jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox({
 beforeShow: function(){
  this.title = $(this.element).next('p').html();
 }
});
```